# Correct name of place showing live concert videos

Tags: adjectives, grammaticality-in-context, modifiers

What is the correct name of a place that shows live concert videos in a hall?

> - Cine live hall
> - Live cine hall
> - Cine live in the hall

The noun takes two adjectives but I can't see which one would come first. I also wonder whether there's a type of event or performance called "cine live."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, English doesn't have a word or phrase for such a place, probably since it's unlikely that there would be a building or facility dedicated to showing live videos/streams of concerts.

One place that might show a live video of a concert would be a *cinema* (British English) or a *movie theater* (American English) (from Oxford Dictionaries):

> [**cinema**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cinema)
>   NOUN
>
> *British*
>   **1** A theatre where films are shown for public entertainment:
>   *"I was weaned on a diet of Hollywood fantasy at my local cinema"*
>   *"I never go to the cinema"*
>
> ---
>
> [**movie theatre**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/movie_theatre) (also **movie house**)
>   NOUN
>
> *North American*
>   A cinema.

In which case, you might use the verb *to show* to say that the cinema is offering customers the opportunity to see live video of the concert:

> [**show**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/show)
>   VERB
>
> **1** Be, allow, or cause to be visible:
>   *[no object] "wrinkles were starting to show on her face"*
>   *"the glow of a city skyline showed up ahead"*
>   *[no object, with complement] "the muscles of her jaws showed white through
>   the skin"*
>   *[with object] "a white blouse will show the blood"*
>   *"a rising moon showed up the wild seascape"*
>
> > **1.3** *[with object]* Present (a film or television programme) on a screen
> >     for viewing:
> >     *"ITV showed The Enforcer on Saturday night"*
> >
> > **1.4** *[with object]* (of a film) be presented for viewing:
> >     *"a movie showing at the Venice Film Festival"*

Or you might say that the cinema was "putting on a showing of (the concert)":

> [**showing**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/showing)
>   NOUN
>
> **1** *[mass noun]* The action of showing something, or the fact of being
>   shown:
>   *"Alsation dog, championship quality, excellent results in showing"*
>
> > **1.1** *[count noun]* A presentation of a cinema film or television
> >     programme:
> >     *"another showing of the three-part series"*

Note that *to show* and *showing* are appropriate for other venues. For example, some community/leisure centres put on showings of films, or a pub might show a sports match. It's also appropriate to use the passive voice (e.g. "that film is being shown at the pub").

Unfortunately, *cine* is not the correct word (unless you're Indian), as *cine* in English is for describing things related to the process of film-making rather than films in general:

> [**cine**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cine)
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> *British*
>   **1** Cinematographic:
>   *"a cine camera"*
>
> > **1.1** *Indian* Relating to cinema:
> >     *"a cine actor"*
>
> ---
>
> [**cinematography**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cinematography)
>   NOUN
>
> *[mass noun]* The art of photography and camerawork in film-making:
>   *"home movie footage with superb cinematography"*